# Is H a non-abelian group of order 8?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $H=\left<C,D\right>$, where $C=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1\\
 -1 &0
 \end{bmatrix}$ and $D=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1\\
 1 &0
 \end{bmatrix}$. We were tasked to show that $H$ is nonabelian of order $8$. What I am thinking of this problem is that I take all products of power of $C$ and $D$ since $H$ is exactly just the set $\{C^iD^j\mid i=1,2,...\}$ but I know it isn't elegant and is in fact exhaustive.

Is there a nicer way of proving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C$ has order $4$, $D$ has order $2$ and $DCD=C^{-1}$, so it is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_4$ of order $8$ (the group of symmetries of a square).

**Edit:** Since $C, D$ satisfy the relations of $D_4$, it is a homomorphic image of $D_4$. But it cannot be a proper homomorphic image by Lagrange theorem because its order is $>4$ So it is isomorphic to $D_4$.

Comment: I'm sorry, Sir, I was lost. Why is it isomorphic to the dihedral group of order 8? Thank you.

Comment: I added the Edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach, there are probably other more elegant ways though.

Notice that $C$ corresponds to a $90$ degree rotation of the plane, and that $D$ corresponds to a flip $D (x_1, x_2) = (x_2, x_1)$. Therefore, $C$ and $D$ act on a square with center at the origin with $C$ being a $90$ degree rotation of the square and $D$ being a flip of the square. It follows that the map
$$ C \to R \qquad D \to F$$
is an isomorphism from $< C, D>$ to $D_8$, the dihedral group with eight elements. $D_8$ is known to be non-abelian and have eight elements.